# Are there any functional differences between xc16 and C30?

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, mplabx, mplab

I've recently istalled MPLAB X (free version) and tried to build an existing project which uses C30. C30 seems to have been replaced with xc16 which does indeed build the project but the resulting .hex file cannot be flashed onto a dspic30f6013a.

Where can I get C30? The error message shown when updating (by ds30Loader) was that the bootloader would be overwritten.

Comment: MPLAB is a product from Microchip, you should ask their support.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I did; I got no answer (on the forums).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XC16 toolchain is the upgrade for the C30 toolchain. The C24 and dsPIC toolchains are subsets of the C30. Have a look [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:work-outside-create-makefiles-xc16)
The difference between xc16 and C30 are quiet small.
Maybe your controller is not supported by the C30 compiler.
For a download of old compilers have a look [here](https://www.microchip.com/development-tools/pic-and-dspic-downloads-archive). The C30 is renamed to PIC C Compiler for PIC24.

Comment: Managed to get a C30 copy from the archives.

Comment: excellent. Hope the link helps